# Facebook iOS SDK Login - "Unsupported request"

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

##### Issue

When we try to log in with developer or testers accounts on iOS, we get the error `Unsupported Request`. Our app was disabled because the tester could not login due to this error.

##### Scenario

- It works on android
- We noted that while the app was in review (activated) users successfully logged in using facebook in iOS devices. That makes us believe this is a problem only with developer and testers accounts
- We also noted that when we try login with a tester account an `openid` item is added to the permissions granted. Before this permission is added we manage to login on web, after this token is added we get the same error on web (`Unsupported request`)
- We already filed a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2747062265594445/) to Facebook and we're waiting for a response.
- We're using the `react-native-fbsdk-next` module and [this issue](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/128) has some more info. We're now trying the approach suggested on [this comment](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/128#issuecomment-976555955)

Have anybody managed to solve this? It really looks like a Facebook Bug.

#### Edit (2021-11-24)

The approach mentioned [here](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/128#issuecomment-976555955) works partially: works when logging in through Safari but does not work when Safari is not logged in and the app is used.

We're still waiting for Facebook's response

###### Facebook SDK versions behavior summary

- v7.0.1 (react-native-fbsdk: 2.0.0):

  - Works when using Safari
  - Does not work when using FB App
- v9.0.1 (react-native-fbsdk-next: 4.2.0):

  - Does not work both through Safari and FB app
- v12.1.0 (react-native-fbsdk-next: 6.1.1):

  - Does not work both through Safari and FB app

#### Edit (2021-11-25)

We removed Facebook integration for the iOS app because we could not keep going without Facebook login for Android users. The app was reactivated and, after that, we generated a new production build and it's working as it should

We're still waiting for Facebook's response

Comment: Do you have an update on this? Or still waiting?